# Using a login form for FOSOAuthServerBundle

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to set up an OAuth server in Symfony using the `FOSOAuthServerBundle` bundle. However, I am getting the following error:

> Client not found.
>
> 404 Not Found - NotFoundHttpException

As far as I can see in the source code, it is looking for a client somewhere. (See code below)

How do I provide it with that information in the form? I've tried putting in a hidden `client_id` field without any success.

```
$request = $this->getCurrentRequest();

$client = null;
if (null !== $request) {
    if (null === $clientId = $request->get('client_id')) {
        $form = $this->container->get('fos_oauth_server.authorize.form');
        $formData = $request->get($form->getName(), array());
        $clientId = isset($formData['client_id']) ? $formData['client_id'] : null;
    }

    $client = $this->container
        ->get('fos_oauth_server.client_manager')
        ->findClientByPublicId($clientId);
}

if (null === $client) {
    throw new NotFoundHttpException('Client not found.');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's expected to be in the URL. This worked out for me:

http://local.dev/oauth/v2/auth?client_id=1_123123123123